# Is there a quick way to check if there is at least one integer in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, numbers

I feel like there is definitely a quick way to check it, instead of having to loop through the entire list.

Comment: One specific integer or any integer (as opposed to float values, or string instances, or etc.)?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
any(isinstance(x, int) for x in list_of_things_that_might_be_ints)
```

This still loops, but the loop is inside the generator expression argument to `any`.  Also, `any` will short-circuit, so if you have a million-entry list, and the second item in the list is an int, then the remaining 999,998 won't be looked at.

Comment: Thanks! Literally added my answer right when you posted yours!

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, just found the answer through a similar question!

Use:

```
if any(isinstance(x, SubclassOne) for x in list_of_stuff):
```

Comment: Not to sound like a jerk but this is why thorough research is appreciated before asking a question on Stack Overflow.